# Use a crawled/mapped property to search

Tags: search, search-results

I've created a site column which has a crawled and managed property.  The site column name is for example: DocType.  If I search for DocType:Memorandum, it show in the results all files that have DocType as Memorandum.

But I want to create a search functionality/screen/web part (I don't know) that displays 'Document Type' with a field next to it.  And when the user enter "Memorandum" in the field and click search, it should search through the site where DocType:Memorandum.

So basically I want to make the search functionality easier for the end user, not to have to remember the name of the mapped properties, but rather just type in the phrase and search should know to search for DocType=Memorandum.  I hope I make sense?

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use a resultpage instead of a web part and modify the refinement panel.
It is very easy to get the managed property as a refinement value with just editing the panel and adding the property (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_made_easy/2013/03/19/step-by-step-configuration-to-add-custom-refiners-in-the-refinement-panel-of-search-results-page-for-sharepoint-online/)

You could also modify the behavior and displayed information by writing your own refiner control template in html / JS (good tutorial could be found here https://www.eliostruyf.com/part-1-create-first-search-refiner-control-template/).

The major drawback would be, that the user has to issue a query first, and then choose to refine for the contenttype after seeing the "unfiltered" results.

It depends on how many different types should be searchable, but you could also create a web part with a search input to type and a choice / button segment beneath it. Depending on the button /choice clicked by the user you add that "refinement" to the query before sending it back.

Comment: That is the problem - the user requirements is that they don't want to search for something and then refine.  They want to search on the actual managed property.  They want to search through out the site for all document types that are = 'Memorandum'.  Do you perhaps know of a link for creating a web part with search input - will that work?